# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have already looked into the answer to [RoR 5.0.0 ActionCable wss WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041614/ror-5-0-0-actioncable-wss-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-301) but it was not applicable to my case.

I use an nginx-proxy as a front for several web-servers running in docker-containers. I use the nginx-config-template from https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Now in my docker-container I have another nginx with the following config:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
default upgrade;
'' close;
}

upstream websocket {
    server my-websocket-docker-container:8080;
}

server {
    root /src/html;


    location /websocket/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    ...

}
```

When trying to connect to **wss://example.com/websocket** I get the aforementioned error about unexpected response code 301. When I curl the websocket-url manually I can see the nginx response telling me "301 moved permanantly". But why? Where is this coming from?

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Your `location /websocket/` has a trailing `/`, but you are connecting to `/websocket` without a trailing `/`. Changing either may remove the redirect.

Comment: yeah that was it, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I did of course try adding the trailing slash before I asked the question, but at that time I had another error causing a timeout 504. Oh what a weekend...

Comment: I would happily upvote and accept your solution in case you want to post it as a regular answer. Thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: @RichardSmith : You are a rockstar. Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue today. I was using the "classic" WebSocket API and NGINX to test the connection between some services. I came up with the following solution:

WebSocket instance creation:

```
const websocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/path');
```

Nginx config:

```
location /path {
    proxy_pass http://websocket:port;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Where:

1. path is the path to be redirected
2. websocket is the hostname or the IP of the host
3. port is the port where the application is served on the host

Comment: When using TLS, don't forget to change protocol to `wss://` instead of `ws://`. Credits to this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966894/896405).

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was because I was using a reverse proxy, with nginx, and it was under SSL.

I was trying to connect to `"ws://..."` / `"http://..."`
But I should connect to `"wss://..."` / `"https://..."`